AWS PHP SDK issue with credentials after upgrading to v3
I have an issue on getting credentials after upgrading from 2nd version to 3rd.
My service gets credentials from metadata server and cache them in file.
Here is how service definition looks like on 2nd version:
my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_cache.adapter:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '%kernel.cache_dir%/aws_credentials'

my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_cache:
        class: Guzzle\Cache\DoctrineCacheAdapter
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_cache.adapter'

my_app.infrastructure.s3.client:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory: [ 'Aws\S3\S3Client', 'factory' ]
        arguments:
            - region: "%my_app_organization_dictionary_aws_s3_region%"
              credentials.cache: '@my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_cache'

With that config it works for a while, after upgrading I changed a way how to cache credentials from metadata server.
    my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_cache.adapter:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '%kernel.cache_dir%/aws_credentials'

    my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_cache:
        class: Aws\DoctrineCacheAdapter
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_cache.adapter'

    my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_provider:
        class: Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider
        factory: [ 'Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider', 'defaultProvider' ]
        public: false

    my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.cached_credentials_provider:
        class: Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider
        factory: [ 'Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider', 'cache' ]
        arguments:
            - '@my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_provider'
            - '@my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.credentials_cache'
        public: false

    my_app.infrastructure.s3.client:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory: [ 'Aws\S3\S3Client', 'factory' ]
        arguments:
            - region: "%my_app_organization_dictionary_aws_s3_region%"
              version: 'latest'
              credentials: '@my_app.infrastructure.s3.client.cached_credentials_provider'

but still get an error
FAIL AWS S3: Fail check the AWS S3 with bucket "my_app_bucket". 
Reason: [Aws\Exception\CredentialsException] 
Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. 
(cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 1001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token).

Any ideas on what's wrong with my setup?

As a general rule, you don't have to interact directly with an EC2 metadata service to get instance profile-based credentials if you're using an official AWS SDK.

I tried to set credentials for s3 client as false but I get 403 error in that case

Assuming that you're running an an EC2 instance with an appropriate IAM role / instance profile, I'm saying that you would not typically need to supply any credentials object to the SDK. The SDK will retrieve them for you. And you should not normally cache these credentials to file. Just let the SDK do its work to retrieve and auto-refresh the AWS credentials as needed.

@jarmod but how to build S3Client for that? without passing credentials I get 403. If I set credentials as false - 401

Don't supply a credentials object at all when using an AWS SDK. See the 'Hello Amazon S3' example here: $client = new S3Client(['region' => 'us-west-2']);

I tried that but my client always try to send requst to metadata server and it fails. Is there chance to avoid call to that server?

Why/how does the request to the metadata service fail? Does your EC2 instance use IMDSv2 but your SDK is back-level?

In my case problem was on AWS config side
Metadata server wasn't accessible from container
This ticket helps me
Using IMDS (v2) with token inside docker on EC2 or ECS

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
